# How to escape Special character in Casandra and janusgrap?

Tags: json, cassandra, janusgraph

Using below special characters, i am getting Json error
How to escape in React or in Casandra Db?

```
"^.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?].*$"
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of a failing gremlin query? Can you also show the stacktrace to see where the error occurs (json serializing of results of Gremlin Server -> use graphbin or gryo serialization)

Comment: @HadoopMarc thanks for your answer.

Here when i used any of these"^.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?].*$" from fronted( i mean from user side) what ever my post in my home page its get hide and in the response its showing ("Unexpected token B in JSON at position 6344")